# Trouble initializing mysql centos 6

Tags: mysql, centos, yum

I'm trying to set up my server and install mysql on it. I got the latest version from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/ 8.0.13 I believe. Everything went well on installation:

```
Installed:

  mysql-community-client.i686 0:8.0.13-1.el6
mysql-community-server.i686 0:8.0.13-1.el6

Dependency Installed:
  libaio.i686 0:0.3.107-10.el6

  mysql-community-common.i686 0:8.0.13-1.el6
  mysql-community-libs.i686 0:8.0.13-1.el6
  numactl.i686 0:2.0.9-2.el6

Complete!
```

However when I try running mysqld using : service mysqld start I get the following error:

> [root@alexdeslauriers ~]# service mysqld start
>       Initializing MySQL database:                               [  OK  ]
>       /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 199:  1181 Killed                  env 
>       MYSQLD_PARENT_
>       PID=999 nohup /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql -- 
>       plugin-
>       dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log -- 
>       pid-fil
>       e=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock < /dev/null> 
>       /d
>       ev/null 2>&1
>       MySQL Daemon failed to start.
>       Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]

Does anyone know what to do to fix this error?

EDIT:

Here is the content of /var/log/mysqld.log

```
2019-01-13T15:20:16.361499Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) initializing of server in progress as process 949
2019-01-13T15:20:23.544739Z 5 [Note] [MY-010454] [Server] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: xxxxxxxxxxx
2019-01-13T15:20:26.283386Z 0 [System] [MY-013170] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) initializing of server has completed
```

Comment: What did you discover when you checked "/var/log/mysqld.log"?

Comment: Nothing it just says the initialization has been complete, I will add it to my post.

Comment: What about `/var/log/messages` - anything in there?